# How to pass data of one function to other and then pass that data inside the view of the other function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this pagination function abc and i want to pass this function to another functions elseif part and in that else if part i want to  pass  $data['books'] through the view... this is my controller and other function is in which i want to pass data of abc function is

```
public function abc($offset = 0){
               $this->load->model('insert_model');
             //$data ['query'] = $this->insert_model->view_data(); 
               $this->load->library('table');

            // Load Pagination
               $this->load->library('pagination');

            // Config setup
            $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/welcome/';
        $items= $config['total_rows'] = 20;
            $perpage=$config['per_page'] = 1;
            // I added this extra one to control the number of links to show up at each page.
            $config['num_links'] = 5;

            // Initialize
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            // Query the database and get results
            // Here we add the limit and the offset
            // The second parameter is the limit, since we are showing
            // 10 per page, the limit should be 10
            $data['books'] = $this->db->get('register',5, $offset);

            // Create custom headers
            $header = array('id','username','lastname','email' , 'password', 'image','status');
            // Set the headings
            $this->table->set_heading($header);
            // Load the view and send the results

        }
```

in the following function's elseif part i want to pass abc functions $data part inside view admin.. how can i pass it so that i can do pagination in that view

```
public function login_process()
    {
        $this->load->model('insert_model');
        $data['users'] = array(
                            'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),

                            'pass'=> $this->input->post('pass'),

                           ); 


        $status= $this->insert_model->login_test($data);
        $st['ss']=$this->insert_model->stat($data); 
        //print "<pre>"; print_r($status); die();
        if($status == true && $st['ss'] [0] ['status'] == 0)
        {
            $ses = array(
                        'username' =>  $this->input->post('fname'),
                        'password' =>  $this->input->post('pass'),
                );

             $this->session->set_userdata($ses);
             $im['pic']=$this->insert_model->image_fetc();

             $this->load->view('header_view',$im);
             $this->load->view('navside_view');
             $this->load->view('user_view');

        }
        elseif($status == true && $st['ss']['0'] ['status'] == 1)
        {
            $ses = array(
                        'username' =>  $this->input->post('fname'),
                        'password' =>  $this->input->post('pass'),
                );

             $this->session->set_userdata($ses);
             $im['pic']=$this->insert_model->image_fetc();
            $this->abc();



             $this->load->view('header_view',$im);
             $this->load->view('navside_view');
             $this->load->view('admin_view', $data);
        }
        else
            {

                $this->load->view('header_view');
             $this->load->view('navside_view');
             $this->load->view('center_view_login');
            }

}
```

in my admin_view i am writing the following code and try to use the data which i have passed to admin view of function abc i.e $aaa code is:-

```
<?php echo $this->table->generate($books); ?>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

but there coming error undefined variable books and this books variable is defined in abc function whose data is passed through loginprocess elseif part in view admin view through $aaa variable please help me to sort it out

Answer (score 0):

```
  you can try this  
    public function abc($offset = 0, $status){
               $this->load->model('insert_model');
             //$data ['query'] = $this->insert_model->view_data(); 
               $this->load->library('table');

            // Load Pagination`enter code here`
               $this->load->library('pagination');

            // Config setup
            $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/welcome/';
        $items= $config['total_rows'] = 20;
            $perpage=$config['per_page'] = 1;
            // I added this extra one to control the number of links to show up at each page.
            $config['num_links'] = 5;

            // Initialize
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            // Query the database and get results
            // Here we add the limit and the offset
            // The second parameter is the limit, since we are showing
            // 10 per page, the limit should be 10
            $data['books'] = $this->db->get('register',5, $offset);
            if($status){
            return $data['books'];
            }

            // Create custom headers
            $header = array('id','username','lastname','email' , 'password', 'image','status');
            // Set the headings
            $this->table->set_heading($header);
            // Load the view and send the results

        }
second function elseif part
elseif($status == true && $st['ss']['0'] ['status'] == 1)
        {
            $ses = array(
                        'username' =>  $this->input->post('fname'),
                        'password' =>  $this->input->post('pass'),
                );

             $this->session->set_userdata($ses);
             $im['pic']=$this->insert_model->image_fetc();
             $aaa = $this->abc(0,true);



             $this->load->view('header_view',$im);
             $this->load->view('navside_view');
             $this->load->view('admin_view', $aaa);
        }
```

Comment: You can simply call abc function wherever you want and store returned values in a variable and pass it to view. If you want only $data['book'] then apply condition
Try to use $variable = $this->abc();
and pass $this->load->view('admin_view', $variable);